# How do you get the side color bar to work for Slack notification attachments?

Tags: slack-api

I'm POSTing the following test json to a Slack Webhook Url:

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "divider"
                },
                {
                    "text": {
                        "text": "This is error 1",
                        "type": "plain_text"
                    },
                    "type": "section"
                },
                {
                    "type": "divider"
                },
                {
                    "text": {
                        "text": "This is error 2",
                        "type": "plain_text"
                    },
                    "type": "section"
                },
                {
                    "type": "divider"
                },
                {
                    "text": {
                        "text": "This is error 3",
                        "type": "plain_text"
                    },
                    "type": "section"
                }
            ],
            "color": "danger"
        }
    ],
    "blocks": [
        {
            "text": {
                "text": "*Failed*\nDeploy <https://google.com|Test>\nTotal tests: 75 Passed: 75 Total time: 54.1872 Seconds\nError Messages:",
                "type": "mrkdwn"
            },
            "type": "section"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in the payload, I'm setting `"color": "danger"` in the attachment object, which should result in a red color bar on the notification [according to Slack's documentation](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments#fields). However, the [Slack notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hxV3.png) just has the default gray color bar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does using a hexcode for the `color` value work instead?

Comment: @sandra Great thought! I tried using the hexcode values and that is working!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the color code. Eg [from their docs](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments):

`"color": "#36a64f"`